# Oracle SQL get records between Previous day and Today within the specified duration

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, toad

How can i fetch all data between Product dates exactly from previous day 9:01AM to till today 9:00 AM (any timezone)?  Below query not giving the data exactly between the time durations. This is dynamic query. Everyday it will be executed.

```
SELECT * from Table1 where product_date > (sysdate-1) - interval '09' hour  and product_date < sysdate - interval '09' hour ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically correct.  You just need to truncate the date:

```
where product_date > trunc(sysdate) - interval '15' hour and
      product_date < trunc(sysdate) + interval '09' hour ;
```

`sysdate` has a time component as well as the date.

Comment: @@Gordon Linoff:  This is working. Suppose if I want with minutes difference also then how? Example: 09:15 AM previous day to 09:14 AM today.

Comment: @venkat . . . You should ask a new question, with appropriate sample data and desired results.  Be clear on what difference you want.